# Easiest way to practice graphics

Tags: graphics, 2d, sdl

I am learning C and wish to create 2D static objects, line graphs etc for GUI graphics and printing. SDL seems too much and there is no clear source available to teach SDL in C. what are my easier choices? I have windows 7 & Fedora 16 (dual OS) on my computer?

Comment: What do you want this for? A game? pixel editor? vector editor? GUI graphics? printing? The choice depends on a number of factors, just "2D graphics" isn't quite enough information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [Allegro](http://alleg.sourceforge.net/index.html). It is somehow similar to SDL, but seems simpler to use. There shouldn't be a problem to find some tutorials.

Some learning resources are listed here ->

http://www.deitel.com/ResourceCenters/Programming/C/AllegroCGameProgramming/tabid/223/Default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[Win32 and GDI](http://www.functionx.com/win32/Lesson15.htm) are pretty easy once you have the basic boiler plate code in.

There of course is OpenGL

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [Cairo graphics](http://cairographics.org/) & [GTK](http://gtk.org/) could be useful to you. If you are interested in C++, the [Qt Graphics View](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/graphicsview.html) should interest you.

They all claim to be multi-platform (running on Windows and on Linux).

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [SDL_draw](http://sdl-draw.sourceforge.net/)? This is a library that runs on top of SDL that provides very simple to use functions for drawing lines, circles, rectangles, etc.